# How to loop an array in Krusto Query for Azure App Insight data?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have encountered a problem which is I have an array of id, I need to filter the output of the query using the id. How can I do it in Krusto because I do not found any operators regarding to loop or foreach.

For example, now I have an array of

```
let id=dynamic(['X0001', 'X0002', 'X0003'])
```

Then I will have to filter the output like

```
myDatabase
| where message has id
| project timestamp, message
```

I expect the output will be the rows that already filtered the message have existence of any id in the array. So I will have to loop the id in the array and check whether it is exist inside the message property or not

How can I achieve this? Really appreciates any helps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [has_any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/has-anyoperator) operator instead of `has` operator.

Change your query like below:

```
let id=dynamic(['X0001', 'X0002', 'X0003']);
myDatabase
| where message has_any (id)
| project timestamp, message
```

Here is the example from official doc:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Can't believe I missed out that in documentation@@